# Using a WPF WebBrowser for Google Auth authentication

Tags: wpf, google-authentication

I am currently following the quickstart guide for using the [Google Tasks API for .NET](https://developers.google.com/tasks/quickstart/dotnet). I have got the demo working but the google authentication account selection thing is done in my default browser.

I would like to keep the users inside my application so instead of redirecting to google chrome etc I would like the authentication to be done inside a WPF WebBrowser widget. The widget can accept a source. Is there a way I can stop the example code (`GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker`?) from opening the default browser and instead send the URL to the widget and then send any information it needs back?